# Intensity of central maximum for a diffraction grating

Tags: optics, laser, diffraction, intensity

If I send a typical 5 mW, 532 nm laser pointer beam through a diffraction grating (~1,000 slits/mm), then I'd expect the beam to cover something like ~1,000 slits. The resulting intensity of the central maximum should then be something like $\sim\left(10^3\right)^2 = 10^6$ times the incident beam intensity.

When I actually perform this experiment though, the central maximum isn't noticeably any brighter or dimmer. In fact, the central bright spot is nearly just as large as the incident bright spot. There are one or two higher-order maxima which suggests that the central max bright spot is probably even dimmer than the incident intensity (given they're of comparable size). Why do I not notice a huge increase in the bright spot intensity? What is breaking down here?

Comment: What do you mean by the "original beam"?

Comment: The incident beam on the slits (as the beam gets split into multiple beams from the grating)

Answer (score 1):

> The resulting intensity of the central maximum should then be something like  ∼$\left(10^3\right)^2 = 10^6$ times the original beam intensity.

The comparison in the formula is not with an unobstructed beam, but with the beam after diffracting through a single slit the same size as those in the grating.

The central peak intensity for a beam that strikes $N$ slits is equal to $N^2$ the central intensity from a single slit.

Comment: AH I see, thank you for the clarification. Looking back through some references that is how $I_0$ was defined. That explains a lot of other similar confusion I've had for a few years now... haha. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I'm not fully satisfied with this on second thought... why can't I take the intensity of the laser beam to be uniform so that it's constant no matter how many slits there are? The intensity over an individual slit should be the same as the intensity over all of the slits for a uniform beam??

Comment: The more slits you have 1) more light comes through and 2) the maxima peaks are narrower.

Comment: Setting aside that first issue ($d = 1.01a$, say), that second one seems plausible to me. So I perceive the central max to be nearly just as bright as a result of the peaks being so narrow. But they're narrowness is imperceptible to me since the beam itself is already on the order of millimeters.

Would you agree with that? That is, that the grating is focusing the beam but that it's imperceptible?

Comment: Possible.  The formula is not for an integrated brightness over all the peaks.